# Django Detail View on Boostrap Modal?

Tags: python, django, templates, bootstrap-modal

Am in the process of building an Ecomerce app with django and although am comming along just fine, I can't seem to be able to render the details of a specific object on a bootstrap modal.

[This is a screenshot of what am trying to get rendered on the modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjVGA.png)

[This is the modal being display but no image or data being passed to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzHct.png)

I went around searching and saw that modals can be rendered with Ajax but haven't found any solid article so far. I would appreciate if anyone could provide a source or a quick sample on how to pull this off.

NOTE: I am able to render the detail view as a standalone view as you can see in the  image that will follow:[Detail View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72E4q.png)

My views:

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    # category_slug parameter gives us the ability to optionally filter 
    # product by a given category
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    # Available=True to filter only the available products
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = products.filter(category=category)

    paginator = Paginator(products, 9)  # Show 9 products per page.
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')

    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    # -> Adds the "add to cart" form to list view
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    context = {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'products': products,
        'cart_product_form': cart_product_form,
        "page_obj": page_obj,

    }
    return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', context)



def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    # id and slug parameters in order to retrieve a product instance
    # Slug parameter added to make the SEO-friendly URLs for products
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,
                                id=id,
                                slug=slug,
                                available=True)

    # -> Adds the "add" to cart form to detail view
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/detail.html',
                  {'product': product, 'cart_product_form': cart_product_form})
```

My App Urls:

```
urlpatterns =[
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('product/', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
```

]

Comment: you can bind event handler when bootstrap modal popup send get request to detail view and populate context data received from it.

Comment: You mean adding an event handler using Java Script?

Comment: you are using jquery right?

Comment: I am, yes. But my issue is that right now I have the modal inside the of my List view template. If I move to another template, the modal won't pop when I click the button that should trigger it. Not sure what am doing wrong or where exactly I should place the target modal

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to pass the ajax URL for loading the respective object details on the button in your list that opens the modal. This would be in the template code:

```html
<ul>
    {% for obj in object_list %}
        <li>
            {{ obj.name }}
            <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#exampleModal"
                    data-ajaxurl="{% url 'product_detail' obj.id obj.slug %}">
                    Open modal
            </button>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Then you need an event handler in your main template (that also contains the modal) to load and update the modal when the button is clicked:

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var ajaxUrl = button.data('ajaxurl') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  
  $('#exampleModal-content').load(ajaxUrl)
})
```

### References

- Bootstrap Modals: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#varying-modal-content
- Working project example: https://gitlab.com/ErikKalkoken/aa-memberaudit/-/blob/master/memberaudit/templates/memberaudit/character_viewer.html#L346

Comment: Much appreciated. I will take a closer look at it and see if I can implement it on my project, Thanks

Comment: Concise and very helpful, perfect!