# Bootsrap modal don't open

Tags: html, django, templates, bootstrap-modal

I have some doubts regarding the modal, which I have been using to see the data, my problem is that when it is inside the same HTML it opens the modal, when it is another HTML, it gives an error.

urls.py

```
    path("modalview/<int:prescription_id>", views.modalview, name="modalview"),
```

Main.html

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered border-primary" id="patientTable" >
        <tbody>
            {% for appointment in appointments %}
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Appointment Number: {{ appointment.id }}</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Doctor Name: {{ appointment.doctor }}</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p>Appointment Date: {{appointment.date}}, {{ appointment.time }}</p></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            {% for prescription in prescriptions %}
                <tr> 
                    <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"   data-ajaxurl="{% url 'modalview' prescription.id }}">     Open modal     </button></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

view.py

```
def modalview(request, prescription_id):
    prescription = Prescription.objects.get(id = prescription_id)
    context={
        'prescription': prescription
    }
    return render(request, "ClinicMan/modalview.html", context)
```

modalview.html

```
{% load static %}

{% block body %}

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label"><p>Symptoms: {{ prescription.symptoms }}</p></label>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label"><p>Prescription: {{ prescription.prescription }}</p></label>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label"><p>Appointment Date: {{ prescription.date }}</p></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  {% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'ClinicMan/script.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

script.js

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var ajaxUrl = button.data('ajaxurl') // Extract info from data-* attributes
    
    $('#exampleModal-content').load(ajaxUrl)
  })
```

For this reason I would like to know if the way I made the code is correct or if something is missing.

I tested it with the modal on the same page, passing only an id and it opened but, in this way, it didn't end up not going.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In order for the modal to work the following must be true:

The script that calls the modal (script.js) must be referenced on the first page (main.html). Otherwise it doesn't exist when you want to use it on the button push.

The element that gets filled with the modal content ('#exampleModal-content') must also be on the first page (main.html), otherwise there's nowhere in the page's Document Object Model (DOM) for the called page content to go. Currenly you don't have an element with an ID of that name. You do have #example-modal but that is not on the first page (main.html) either so it won't work as you currently have it.

main.html

```
 ...
 </table>

 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div id="exampleModal-content">
      </div>
 </div>

   {% block script %}
    <!-- move this to main.html so that the button can see it -->>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'ClinicMan/script.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

modalview.html

```
<!-- we've removed the top div so the main.html template knows where to put things -->
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="modal-dialog">
```

Comment: I used what is written on this page as an example, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271709/django-detail-view-on-boostrap-modal)

Comment: That example has the modal on the same page, you need to treat things a little differently.  I've put in some examples that might make things clearer.